# Where to put message file in codeigniter4?

Tags: codeigniter-4

I want to create a separate file called `custom_message.php`. What will be the location of this file in CI4 project structure and how to call in controller.

Example:

```
$arr_custom_message = [

'msg_add' => 'Admin Created!',
'msg_update' => 'Updated Successfully!'

];
```

Comment: Are you referring to language translations, custom application configurations, helpers, or neither?

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa No!

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa I am new in CI so I have confusion so please help me out here.

Comment: Are you looking to display messages after a function success or fail? Please explain a little more so I can assist.  Most of the time the file will be in the `Views/layouts` folder and will be called by the main layout file. But I need to know more to walk you through properly.

Comment: @DeanE10 
I want to store all messages (like in my que) in (key->value) array. I am not clear about the place where it should be available. And how to call it in view or controller?

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/localization.html

Comment: @MayurKoshti You can use the [Codeigniter Settings](https://github.com/codeigniter4/settings) table for this. Tatter makes a plugin as well and shows a [few examples on his page](https://github.com/tattersoftware/codeigniter4-settings)